# Encoding maps in JWT headers

Tags: go, jwt

I'm trying to figure out how to encode a map in a JWT using the following JWT library:

```
https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
```

The JWT that I need to be able to produce has the following payload:

```
{
  "iss": "id.example.com",
  "aud": "notify",
  "iat": 1602681257,
  "exp": 1602682157,
  "payload": {
    "data": {
      "name": "bob",
      "id": "123456",
    },
    "type": "CUSTOM"
  },
  "env": "integration",
}
```

The standard claims are easy to produce, but I couldn't figure out from the docs how to generate the data under "payload", since it's not a single value, but a map. The code for testing that I currently have is the following:

```
package main
  
import (
        "crypto/ecdsa"
        "crypto/elliptic"
        "crypto/rand"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        key, _ := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)

        timestamp := time.Now().Unix()

        claims := jwt.StandardClaims{
                Audience: "notify",
                ExpiresAt: timestamp + 60,
                Issuer: "id.example.com",
                IssuedAt: timestamp,
        }

        token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodES256, claims)
        token.Header["kid"] = "foobar"
        tokenString, _ := token.SignedString(key)

        fmt.Println(tokenString)
}
```

How can I generate the rest of the claims in the JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your issue is that you're trying to define your custom payload in the JWT header when you really want it in the claims section.

The jwt package provides a `MapClaims` type which allows you to define your claims in a loosely typed way. If you'd like to have stronger typing on your claims, you could use struct embedding to define your own claim type by doing something like the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

type payload struct {
    Data map[string]string `json:"data,omitempty"`
    Type string            `json:"type,omitempty"`
}

type customClaims struct {
    jwt.StandardClaims
    Payload payload `json:"payload,omitempty"`
    Env     string  `json:"env,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    key, _ := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)

    timestamp := time.Now().Unix()

    claims := customClaims{
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            Audience:  "notify",
            ExpiresAt: timestamp + 60,
            Issuer:    "id.example.com",
            IssuedAt:  timestamp,
        },
        Env: "integration",
        Payload: payload{
            Type: "CUSTOM",
            Data: map[string]string{
                "name": "bob",
                "id":   "123456",
            },
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodES256, claims)
    tokenString, _ := token.SignedString(key)

    fmt.Println(tokenString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MapClaims:

```
   claims:=map[string]interface{} {
      "payload": map[string]interface{} {
       ...
       },
       ...
   }
   token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodES256, jwt.MapClaims(claims))
```